# how to convert an array into an array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, object

I have an array like [1,2,3]
I want to convert this array into [{"weeklyDays" : 1}, {"weeklyDays" : 2}, {"weeklyDays" : 3}].

I tried to do like this. but not working.

```
const arrayValue = [1,2,3];
arrayValue.map((index)=> {
  return {
    "weeklyDays" : index
  }
});
```

Comment: It's working on my browser's console

Comment: There's no point in using `parseInt` on something that's already a number. It's for parsing *strings*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Try This**

```
const arrayValue = [1,2,3];
var newArray = [];

arrayValue.forEach((value) => {
  newArray.push({"weeklyDays": value});
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: That's a very long winded way to get the same effect as using `map` which fails to explain why the original code didn't work.

Comment: @Quentin - I see someone downvoted your answer here, probably soon after my comment. Hopefully you know that it wasn't me. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — I suspect it was at the horror of me focusing on the problem and not cleaning up the pointless parseInt. ‍♂️

Comment: @Quentin so I was doing right thing ?

Comment: @ParagRaje — See the duplicate question for an explanation as to why your code appears not to work.

Comment: @Quentin got that.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
[1,2,3].map((value) => { weeklyDays: parseInt(value) })
```